# UIBModal animation override

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to override the default animation for UIBModal. However this is not working. The default animation runs only.

```
.modal.modal-slide-in-right .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(20%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(20%, 0%);
  -o-transform: translate(20%, 0%);
  transform: translate(20%, 0%);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .5, .5, .9) 1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .5, .5, .9) 1s;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .5, .5, .9) 1s;
}

.modal.modal-slide-in-right.in .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YQ0eHIWrHlm90oW5oS4r?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to insert your `extra.css` stylesheet into the `index.html`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="extra.css">`

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zxOIFYtsYtV2aGkZ0kWD?p=preview)